# ¿Como arreglo la advertencia "character constant too long for its type"?

Tags: c++, warnings

Necesito crear un programa que, escoja un deporte y si el deporte es natación diga un mensaje y si no que diga otro mensaje. Para esto usé char junto con if y else, pero en la parte de if, me manda una advertencia diciendo  "character constant too long for its type". La línea marcada es donde me manda la advertencia
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En tu código declaraste la variable letra de typo `char`, y las variables `char` solo almacenan un caracter. Obviamente si lo comparas con la palabra 'natacion' te va a dar un error, porque natación tiene 8 caracteres y el compilador espera solo 1 caracter. De ahí que te diga `"character constant too long for its type"`, es decir, la constante con que comparas es demasiado grande, el está esperando un `char`.

Tienes varias soluciones. Si gustas que el usuario escriba el deporte completo, prueba `strcmp`, un método para comparar dos strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char deporte[9];
    printf("Introduzca un deporte \n");
    scanf("%s",deporte);

    if (strcmp(deporte,"natacion") == 0)
        printf("El deporte es natacion");
    else
        printf("El deporte no es natacion");

    return 0;
}
```

De lo contrario podrías pedir al usuario un número, algo así:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char deporte;
    printf("Seleccione el deporte \n");
    printf("1- Natacion \n");
    printf("2- Futbol \n");
    printf("3- Baloncesto \n");
    scanf("%c", &deporte);

    if (deporte == '1')
        printf("El deporte es natacion");
    else
        printf("El deporte no es natacion");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue de gran ayuda

Comment: @ChristopherSibaja considera aceptar la respuesta correcta a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Eso pasa porque las comillas simples son para caracteres y las comillas dobles son para una lista de caracteres (también aplica para std::string) ([Más información](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-cplusplus)).

Además en tu código agregaste un char en vez de char* para una lista de caracteres, cámbialo para que te compile también, aparte incluiste iostream en C, para las funciones de printf y scanf deberías incluir stdio.h (si ese programa no está deliberadamente hecho para C también modifica "string.h" a "string" para que pueda ser encontrado por el compilador en la carpeta include).

```
char* hola = "hola como les va"; // ok
```

```
char* hola = 'hola como les va';
char saludo = 'hola como les va';
char greeting = "hola como les va";
// Errores
```